# Run realm.io inside watchos2 extension

Tags: cocoapods, realm, watchos-2

I try to migrate my existing Apple Watch app to watchos2 but fail to get realm.io running on the watchkit extension.

The [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-20) describes how to get everything running with Swift 2.0:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Realm', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0' 
pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
```

And on [Realm news from end of June](https://realm.io/news/realm-support-xcode7-swift2-watchos-bitcode/) it was mentioned that watchos support is on the way with [Pull Request 2139](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2139). It seems that changes in this PR are not merged into any branch.

When I run the watchkit extension with the `swift-2.0` branch I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
....
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/.../DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework/Realm: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Are there any plans to merge the watchos2 support soon and make it accessible? Or are there other recommendations or resources to get Realm running on the Apple Watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What versions of Xcode and CocoaPods are you using? I believe that CocoaPods actually needs some unreleased functionality to work completely with watchOS 2 apps, see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4004, which will be included in the upcoming 0.39 release.

Comment: I am using XCode 7 beta 5 and CocoaPods 0.38.2. I just tested with 0.39.0.beta.1 but still get the same problem.
Other Cocoapod dependencies work on my watchkit extension. Seems to be a problem in the Realm pod.

Comment: Can you try again with Xcode 7 Beta 6? We've seen that the newest beta has fixed a bunch of watchOS-related issues.

Comment: I tried with Xcode 7 Beta 6 and Cocoapods 0.39.0.beta.1 and it still does not work out of the box.
I noticed that the _Embed Pods Frameworks_ run script is missing in the extension target's Build Phase. I added the run script `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyAppExtension/Pods-MyAppExtension-frameworks.sh"` and now it works again!